# how can I print ascii code value in c++ in this way?

Tags: c++

I'd like to show each letter's ascii code
for example

---

Input: HelloWorld

### Ascii Value: 72 + 101 + 108 ... = 1100

And here's my now-code

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[32] = { 0 };
    int value = 0, i;
    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> str;
    for (i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        value += str[i];
    }

    cout << "Ascii Value:" << value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

I only can take the total value of ascii code such as 1100,
not every code value of each letters such as 7 + 11 + ... = 1100.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to print value of each char separately.

Comment: Can I ask you how can I? I have no idea about it.

Comment: Your printable non-whitespace character values are between `32 - 127` , you are not going to print anything printing the total, unless you store each character value in a nul-terminated character array and then print that. (or print each value separately, e.g.. `cout << str[i];`)

Comment: What is the purpose of your program? Adding ASCII encoded characters doesn't really serve any purpose.

Comment: Do you want your output to be like "97 + 97 = 194" for the input of "aa"?

Comment: Irregardless of my previous comment, you have to remember that if you attempt to use `<<` to print a character, it will be printed as the character. If you want to get its encoded value you need to convert the character to an integer type which is not a `char`.

Comment: Perhaps push your values onto a vector of ints?

Comment: Pranav Totla  - exactly.

Comment: To output the ASCII value of a single character, cast it into an int like `cout << int(str[i])`. Now you just need to output the plus signs, spaces, and the equal sign. You should also use C++ strings instead of char arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a string for your input (it's c++, not c). Your for loop sums 32 characters, even if the user inputs a shorter string (the programm will read random values from memory). For conversion from `int` to `char` you can use `stringstream`. This results in

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::stringstream sstr;
    int value = 0;
    std::cout << "Input: ";
    std::cin >> input;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        sstr << int(input[i]) << " + ";
        value += input[i];
    }

    std::string str(sstr.str());
    std::cout << "Ascii Value:" << str.substr(0, str.size() - 3) << " = " << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So thanks to your kindness! But, error message come out from your code. Does it work in your compiler?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There was an error. I fixed it.